# ACF field value display on woocommerce category archive page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, archive

I am working on woocommerce  based webiste. I have create field through **ACF** called **Add Sub title** for woocommerce  **product** post type . I want to display that field value after Main Title on woocommerce category archive page.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_sub_title', 3 );

function display_sub_title() {
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
$add_sub_title = get_field('add_sub_title',$id);
    if ( $add_sub_title ) { ?>
        <h5><?php echo $add_sub_title; ?></h5>
    <?php }
}
```

I have place above code in functions.php file but it's not working. How can I display sub-title under main title on category archive page. ??

Comment: Have you tested a different priority, ex **10, 0**? Have you tested the field actually returns a value?

Answer (score 1):

I use this and works good

```
function show_subtitle() {
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();
$subtitle = get_field('sottotitolo',$id);
    if ( $subtitle ) { 
        echo '<span>'.$subtitle.'</span>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_subtitle', 3 );
```